# Calculate the amount based on number of miles and calendar year

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out how to calculate a value based on a calendar year.

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var tbl = $('.pcd_disburse');
    tbl.find('tr').each(function () {
        // $this = this;
        $(this).find('input[type=text]').on("change", function () {
            calcMileage();
        });
    });

    function calcMileage() {
        var rateC = 0.53; // CO mileage rate 2017
        var rateB = 0.55; // CO mileage rate 2018
        var rateA = 0.58; // CO mileage rate 2019
        var getYear = $('.ndate').val();
        var year = getYear.slice(-2);
        var tbl = $('.pcd_disburse');
        tbl.find('tr').each(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            $(this).find('.ntotal').each(function () {
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0 && year === '17') {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value * rateC);
                } else if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0 && year === '18') {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value * rateB);
                } else {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value * rateA);
                }
            });
            $(this).find('.miltotal').val('$' + sum.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
        });
    }
});
```

It's not calculating correctly. The goal is to calculate the number of miles multiply by the rate base on the calendar year. Any recommendation is appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not calculating correctly?" An example input, the expected output, and the actual output would be very helpful.

Comment: If I enter let's say 01/09/2019 on the date field and input 10 on the number of miles field, it will calculate the correct rate based the var Rate on the first row. However, if I enter 11/09/2081 on the second row date field and enter 10 again on the number of miles field, it calculates the amount based on the last value, 1st row, and not base on the calendar year. Basically if I enter 01/09/2019 and enter 10 as the number of miles, it should be 10 * 58 based. And if I enter 11/09/2018 on the second row and claim 10 miles, it should be 10 * 55, not 10 * 58. **grammar bad**

Comment: Are you sure that regex is behaving correctly? If you just display the sum.toFixed(2) value is that right. Also as Calvin requested give some examples of what you enter and what you actually get. i.e. "Should be 10 * 58 based" but I actually get ...

Comment: Thanks. I removed 'replace'. Here's a sample of what I'm trying to accomplish. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xFStK2YXcykBMDKPI6e-lP9TiH1hFGiW/view?usp=sharing